# differentiate $f(x) = xe^{-\ln x}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have used product rule to make $u=x$ and $v=e^{- \ln x}$. I get $u=1$ but I'm unsure what $dv$ should be. Would it be $dv=- \ln xe^{- \ln x}$ or $dv=- \ln e^{- \ln x}$ and then that would simplify to $dv= \ln x$?

Comment: Notice that $e^{-\ln x} = (e^{\ln x})^{-1} = x^{-1}$

Comment: As an exercise, you could also try integrating $x^{^\tfrac x{\ln x}}$ :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you remember your rules of logarithms, note that $$-\ln x=-1\cdot\ln x=\ln x^{-1},$$ so that $$e^{-\ln x}=x^{-1}=\frac1x.$$ Hence, $$xe^{-\ln x}=x\cdot\frac1x=1$$ for all $x>0,$ which makes our task a great deal simpler.

Answer (score 2):

$$e^{-\ln x} = \left( e^{\ln x}\right)^{-1} = (x)^{-1} = \frac 1x$$

$$x e^{-\ln x} = x\cdot \frac 1x$$Now, what is $x \cdot \dfrac 1x$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Full calculation:

$[xe^{-\ln x}]'=x'e^{-\ln(x)}+x[e^{-\ln(x)}]'=e^{-\ln(x)}-x[\ln(x)]'e^{-\ln(x)}=(1-x\cdot \frac 1x)e^{-\ln(x)}=0$